# Security Policy Error after Installing iPhone SDK 3.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.1

I'm working on an iPhone project in which the developer that created it has left the company. The Boss asked me to ensure it compiles on the 3.1 iPhone SDK.

After installing, it built and ran fine just once on the device.

After that, it still builds okay, but if I try to run it on the device, it halts saying 
Error from Debugger: Error launching remote program: Security policy Error

It won't play in the simulator either, except this time it just says "Debugging Terminated"

Does anybody have any ideas about what might be causing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem ended up being that there was a provisioning profile (from a completely different project) that had expired. I don't know why having this unrelated profile expire would cause this problem.

Deleting the expired profile from the iPhone fixed the problem.

Comment: Just had the same problem and found your solution Kevin.  Worked for me to.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have written down a tutorial to solve this:

http://www.drooljunkie.com/code-uncode/beginning-iphone-app-dev-issues-part-2-running-app-on-the-device-issues/

Answer (score 0):

in my case I removed those with the same name ...